# php form post method

Tags: php

I am trying to pass array using form post method :

submit.php

```
<form method="post"   action="makepub.php"> 
<?php
....   Loop
....   
echo '</td><td align="center">';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="file_list[]" value="'.$pr.'">' ;
echo '</td><tr/>';     
....
....   Loop end
?>

makepub.php   :
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) { 
     $file_list = $_POST["file_list"];
     $how_many = count($file_list); 
echo '<b>Total No of Public files chosen : </b>'.$how_many.'<br><br>'; 
if ($how_many>0) { 
     echo '<b>You changed following files to public : </b><br>'; 
          } 
for ($i=0; $i<$how_many; $i++) { 
     echo   ($i+1) . '- ' . $file_list[$i] . '<br>'; 
     //   Some code here
} 
     echo "<br><br>"; 
}
```

Ok these two files works perfectly on my localhost with XAMPP. 
php version 5.3

but on my server array is not getting passed. 
I checked by replacing the array with single variable. Even so nothing is passed to file makepub.php

Is there anything i am missing with post here ???
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try var_dump($_POST) to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as it appears, however you should make sure your submit button has a name of submit1 and then you close the form with a closing tag.

Comment: I have narrowed down my problem. :

The method in makepub.php fails that may be due old values that remains there. If i want to flush my variables how can this be done effectively while not destroying the sessions.